# Schedule POD alone on a node

Tags: kubernetes

We're trying to isolate a problem with a specific pod and we would like to have it deployed all by itself on a node. (except for kube-system pods)

Is there a simple way to get a high priority pod to be scheduled by itself ? (ex: set cpu requests to 100% )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should not pin Pods to a specific node - so there are no specific feature for that in Kubernetes.

But you can achieve this in multiple ways anyway.

> (ex: set cpu requests to 100% )

Yes, if your nodes are homogeneous (e.g. all have the same CPU amount) then, I think this is the best method. If your nodes has e.g. 4 CPU cores, you can set the CPU request to 3.5 or something (depending on how much the kube-system pods requests).

Using [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) might be another way to solve this.

Comment: I considered nodeSelector, but I need to recreate nodes to get their label setup. I'll keep using CPU requests. It's only for a few days to investigate the issue

Comment: see the answer from mdaniel, that is a better approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is the problem that [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) was designed to solve

I would guess most kube-system things have a "universal" toleration, designed to work with all taints (and if not, one can trivially add one as follows:)

```yaml
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    operator: Exists
```

Then, you would just taint the Node with some nonsense key, and add the matching toleration to the Pod or Deployment you wish to insolate